# How to add interpreter to PhpStorm 2016.1.1

Tags: php, installation, phpstorm, interpreter, jetbrains-ide

I am brand new to PHP, but very familiar with JetBrains IDEs, so I chose PhpStorm as my IDE to learn. I can create PHP files just fine, however finding and installing an interpreter has proven to be an issue I can't figure out. I have downloaded PHP version 7.0.6 from php.net, but it is just a directory with **a lot** of files and folders in it, no executable (such as Python 2.7 or 3.x to simply install the interpreter on the system).

How do I load the PHP interpreter into PhpStorm?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Copy the php directory to the root folder of your Web server

Then 
Open phpstorm

1. Click File > settings to open the preferences dialog and click PHP under Languages and Framework
2. On the PHP page that opens click on the button next to the interpreter
3. On the interpreter dialog box,  click add toolbar on the left hand pane, and choose local from the context menu
4. On the right hand pane specify the PHP interpreter settings

   - in the name text box,  enter any name to identify the interpreter, for example,  `php_installatuon_7`
   - Specify the location of the php installation directory by typing manually or click the browse button and choose the location in the dialog box
5. Click OK to complete the process

Screenshots below to guide you through the process

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]
4. [image]

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/configuring-local-php-interpreters.html

Answer (score 0):

In case  "**php language level**" Field is disabled you can simply change your PHP version in

**composer.json** file

```
"require": {
"php": ">=X.X.X",
}

//...
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "X.X.X"
    },//...
```

also if you have problem in **Composer** delete it (composer.phar) and download it again